# secure_file_priv= NULL in mySQL workbench MAC

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to mySql workbench and need help importing a large file for analysis. I read here
[MySQL workbench table data import wizard extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296569/mysql-workbench-table-data-import-wizard-extremely-slow) that the data import wizard shouldn't be used so i used LOAD DATA INFILE as suggested but I had issues importing due to `secure_file_priv=NULL`.

I found a solution here [How should I tackle --secure-file-priv in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql) but I don't know how to reset the value of `secure_file_priv`.

I found some sources that use command line to do so but I don't know how to use mySql workbench from command line.

Any help on how to disable this or change it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

don't touch it, it is basicakky a security feature.

use the data import under server in workbench,

[image]

If you want  do it by sql, ecery thng os written already in [How should I tackle --secure-file-priv in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql)  which you linked

simple
copy your file in the folder, that you get as value, when you do a `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";`

Now you can make a [LOAD DAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) ideally from the console, because then you have no timeout.

Read also [Bulk insert in the namual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) so that you can optimize a big data import

If you really want to use any folder which is **not recommended**, you have to edit the `my.ini` file for that and restart to server (both can be done in Workbench as well, you see in the picture `options file` and `Start/shutdown`.) There are some other ways do restart the service.

Here are the basics good described of [importing csv](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/)

Comment: thanks for the reply ```SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv"``` only shows the value of the variable. it cant be used to change the variable. and Data Import is not taking .csv files. its only taking .dumps files

Comment: no, if you copy the file in that folder, you can use Load In file as i stated in my answer.  if you want to edit it, you have to edit my.ini and restart it as also stated in my answer., Please show the error message that you get and also the sql command

Comment: there is no file or directory path. ```"secure_file_priv"``` is set to NULL

Comment: i tried to reset ```"secure_file_priv``` using SET but it was giving me an error that this action cant be perfomed

Comment: no i mean when you try to load the file, if secure_file_priv is empyt you can choose every folder , that you workbench or mysql client has access to

Comment: its not empty, its set to NULL, those are two different things

Comment: no, they aren't tyr to load the file and see what happemns

Comment: the error is variable ```"secure_file_priv"``` is a read only variable

Answer (score 0):

The reason that ***secure_file_priv*** is null is because usually the software for the server side is install on the server  while in our case the **mysql server is installed on the same mac** (which serve as client and server).
it is the daemon (service running the back) which you could find through system
[mysql daemon (service) that is installed on the same mac][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vlF4.png

and the ***client*** is the ***mysql workbench***
so in order to enable importing from a file you need to set the permission on both side

1. For the server side:

running this command inside  will do the trick
***set global local_variable = on  ;***
you can check if it is on using this command:
***show global variables like 'local_infile';***
[enabling local importing on the server][2]
[2]:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQH1W.png

2. As for the workbench mysql client side you need to add

OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1 to the advanced section under connection:
right click on the ***local instance*** > ***edit connection*** > ***advanced*** the ***add the line***: ***OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1***
[enabling the local input on the client][3]
[enabling the local input on the client][4]
[3]:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlpV0.png
[4]:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0RtR.png

3. restart both client and server
4. Then add the word local to the command  as follow:
   ***load data local infile ‘file path’*** ............