# How can I insert a lot of data into mySQL database at once?

Tags: php, mysql

I insert data from a text file into mySQL database and there will be inserted around 6000 or more entries at once.

```
try {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO data (id,name,date,place) values(?,?,?,?) ";
   $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   foreach($data as $row) {
      $q->execute(array($row['id'], $row['name'], $row['date'], $row['place']));
   }
}
catch (PDOException $pe) {
   echo $pe->getMessage();
}
catch (Exception $e ) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I tried it with 3000 entries and everything works fine. But if I have more data to be inserted it happens that my page is blank and nothing is inserted into my database.

What could cause this problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: The page should not be blank. Turn on error reporting and see what kind of error are you getting.

Comment: Have you tried increasing script timeout?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Should't `catch (PDOException $pe) {
   echo $pe->getMessage();}` give me an error message?

Comment: @madforstrength How exactly do I increase script timeout?

Comment: `set_time_limit(0);` will set timeout to infinite

Comment: @madforstrength: I wrote `set_time_limit(0);` after `try {` but it is still not working`

Comment: Try using     LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';         If you are facing difficulty in the syntax, better try importing data using a tool,some like [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already have text file then use below query

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file/path/to/file.txt' 
INTO TABLE table-name 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Make sure your data in file is in sequence with your table rows.

Read more here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1):

> NSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas. Example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

From [How to do a batch insert in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running multiple queries inside a loop, you should use the multi-insert syntax. Example:

```
INSERT INTO data (id,name,date,place) VALUES (:id1,:name1,:date1,:place1), (:id2,:name2,:date2,:place2), (:id3,:name3,:date3,:place3);
```

Check out [this article](http://thisinterestsme.com/pdo-prepared-multi-inserts/) on doing multi-inserts with prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure how exactly you mean it, I cannot write name1,name2,name3 etc. because I have for example 5000 names and do not know exactly how many.

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

refer to [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32702768)

If you use PDO or the like with looping, you are doing it wrong, and slow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this seem to be a very nice solution, but it seems to be very difficult, I still do not understand how it works. I am parsing the text file and put everything into variables to make a check before I am inserting the data into the database. Do I have to write my code totally new?

Comment: The point is to let mysql and load data infile handle it for you versus you in slow loops. They built that functionality in for performance, and to keep people from sweating the loops, whether in PHP, Java, you name it. Plus it outperforms by factors of 10